# How to delete older image from public folder on upload using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, file, delete-file

I have folder in my public folder profile_images where my images are being stored. I want to delete older image from this folder when new image is uploaded.

How I can delete my older file on upload?

Here is my whole controller code:

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    $image = $request->input('image');
    $r = [
        'user_id' => $user_id,

    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($r, [
        'user_id' => 'required|exists:users,id',

    ]);
    if($validator->fails()) {
        return response(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Validation Errors', 'errors' => $validator->errors()->all()], 500);
    }

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => __('messages.validation_errors'),
            'errors' => $validator->errors()->all()], 200);
    }
    try {
        $path = public_path('profile_images');
        @mkdir($path, '0777', true);

        $image = base64_decode($image);

        $imageName = str_random(10).'.'.'png';
        Storage::disk('profile-image')->put($imageName, $image);

        $path = asset('public/profile_images/' . $imageName);

        $this->userBasicInfo->where('user_id', $user_id)->update(['profile_pic' => $path]);

        return response(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Image Uploaded successfully', 'data' => ['profile_image' => $path]], 200);

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return response(['status' => false, 'message' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd take a look at `unlink`, though not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: i also tried to use unlink but not work it says unlink(): http does not allow unlinking

Comment: any other better solution

Comment: You need to use a file path if you want to delete something using `unlink`. So make sure you're using a path like `public/profile_images/whatevertheimageis.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel have methods to deleting files:

```php
Storage::delete('profile-image/old_file.jpg');
```

Also, you should to remember old file name to delete it in the future:

```php
$imageName = str_random(10).'.'.'png';
```

Save this imageName somewhere or use your user_id to know what image you want to delete.

Comment: i will add file name manually ? like you said ('profile-image/78777.jpg) ?

Comment: If you want to save the user profile image, you just can save this image with the id of this user.

Answer (score 0):

The default method to delete any file in public directory

```
File::delete(public_path('file path and name'));
```